# How to compare array values with object properties in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, lodash

This is my array:

```
const ids = [
  "id1",
  "id2",
  "id3"
]
```

Object that is extracted via cookies

```
const data = [
    {
      id: "id3" // dynamically populated and can vary, we need this property
      prop2: "prop2", // not needed
      prop3: "prop3" // not needed
    }
]
```

How can I compare first array values - `ids` with `data.id`, and if `true`, show some logic (for example - `console.log(true)`? I need it in `if statement`.

Please **note** that `data.id`. can be anything, from `id1` to `id3`. I need to find a way to dynamically compare these values. In "real world" it id anything from `1` do `50000`, but this is just a mock-up for the example.

Also I would appreciate Lodash example.

Comment: Your mean is `ids[0] == data.id`, aren't you ?

Comment: Yes in this example, but data.id can be anything - from `id1` to `id3` (in real world it can be up to `50000`, this is just for this question example).

Also, please don't downvote, or at least write why.

Comment: I think you have been downvoted because by the sites rules, you need to show in your question some code where you tried to sleve your problem, which you do not have.

Comment: Your question is unclear, you want check `data.id` match anything of `ids ` ?

Comment: That is, Lazar, because I don't know how to compare in `if else`..

Comment: Yes Hongarc, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each item in data, you check if the id is in the array of ids, and if yes, do something

```
const ids = [
    "id1",
    "id2",
    "id3"
]

const data = [
  {
      id: "id3", // dynamically populated and can vary, we need this property
      prop2: "prop2", // not needed
      prop3: "prop3" // not needed
   }
]

// if we have the id in ids array, do something
if (data.some(d => ids.indexOf(d.id) > -1)) {
  // do something
}
```

Using lodash:

```
const ids = [
    "id1",
    "id2",
    "id3"
]

const data = [
  {
      id: "id3", // dynamically populated and can vary, we need this property
      prop2: "prop2", // not needed
      prop3: "prop3" // not needed
   }
]

// if we have the id in ids array, do something
if (_.some(data, d => ids.indexOf(d.id) > -1)) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate all the elements in Array which are objects and using `Object.keys`, iterate all the keys in that object which could be compared with initial array of values.

```js
const ids = [
  "id1",
  "id2",
  "id3"
];

const data = [{
  id: "id3", // dynamically populated and can vary, we need this property
  prop2: "prop2", // not needed
  prop3: "prop3" // not needed
}];

const foundElems = [];
data.forEach((el) => {
  Object.keys(el).forEach(elem => {
    if (ids.indexOf(el[elem]) > -1) {
      var Obj = {};
      Obj[elem] = el[elem];
      foundElems.push(Obj);
    }
  });
});
console.log(foundElems);
```

Comment: You can user lodash as well. logic remains same. `_.forEach` is what you need.

Comment: Ok, but I need to do it in `if else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
if (ids.indexOf(data.id) !== -1){
  console.log('true')
}
```

Comment: Read again please.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the next code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="compareIds()">Click me</button>
    <script>
        const ids = [
              "id1",
              "id2",
              "id3"
            ]

        const data = [
                {
                  id: "id3", // dynamically populated and can vary, we need this property
                  prop2: "prop2", // not needed
                  prop3: "prop3" // not needed
                }
            ]

        function compareIds(){
                var dataObject = findDataInObject();
                for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
                        if (ids[i] == dataObject){
                            console.log("true");
                        }

                        else{
                            if(i == ids.length -1){
                                console.log("false");
                            }
                    }
                }
        }

        function findDataInObject(){
                    for(key in data) {
                        if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            var ArrayOfData = data[key];
                            var IdOfData = ArrayOfData.id;
                            return IdOfData;
                        }
                    }
                }


    </script>
</body>
```